# Coq: Associativity of relational composition

Tags: functional-programming, coq, algebra, formal-verification, formal-methods

I am working on verifying a system based on relation algebra. I found D. Pous's relation algebra library popular among the Coq society.

https://github.com/damien-pous/relation-algebra

On this page, binary relation `hrel` is defined together with its relational composition `hrel_dot`.

http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/damien.pous/ra/html/RelationAlgebra.rel.html

In this library, a binary relation is defined as

```
Universe U.
Definition hrel (n m: Type@{U}) := n -> m -> Prop.
```

And the relational composition of two binary relations is defined as

```
Definition hrel_dot n m p (x: hrel n m) (y: hrel m p): hrel n p :=
  fun i j => exists2 k, x i k & y k j.
```

I believe that the relational composition is associative, i.e.

```
Lemma dot_assoc:
  forall m n p q (x: hrel m n) (y: hrel n p) (z: hrel p q),
  hrel_dot m p q (hrel_dot m n p x y) z = hrel_dot m n q x (hrel_dot n p q y z).
```

I got to the place where I think the LHS and RHS of the expressions are equivalent, but I have no clues about the next steps.

```
______________________________________(1/1)
(exists2 k : p,
   exists2 k0 : n, x x0 k0 & y k0 k & z k x1) =
(exists2 k : n,
   x x0 k & exists2 k0 : p, y k k0 & z k0 x1)
```

I don't know how to reason about the nested `exists2`, although the results seem straightforward by exchanging the variables `k` and `k0`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure you can prove the *equality* of those two expressions, at least not without proof irrelevance. If you rewrite your goal as a logical equivalence things should be easier.

Comment: Binary relation algebra is not relational algebra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ana pointed out, it is not possible to prove this equality without assuming extra axioms. One possibility is to use functional and propositional extensionality:

```
Require Import Coq.Logic.FunctionalExtensionality.
Require Import Coq.Logic.PropExtensionality.

Universe U.
Definition hrel (n m: Type@{U}) := n -> m -> Prop.

Definition hrel_dot n m p (x: hrel n m) (y: hrel m p): hrel n p :=
  fun i j => exists2 k, x i k & y k j.

Lemma dot_assoc:
  forall m n p q (x: hrel m n) (y: hrel n p) (z: hrel p q),
  hrel_dot m p q (hrel_dot m n p x y) z = hrel_dot m n q x (hrel_dot n p q y z).
Proof.
intros m n p q x y z.
apply functional_extensionality. intros a.
apply functional_extensionality. intros b.
apply propositional_extensionality.
unfold hrel_dot; split.
- intros [c [d ? ?] ?]. eauto.
- intros [c ? [d ? ?]]. eauto.
Qed.
```